# What's the best practice of typing hint after python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

After python3.9, there are at least three ways to use typing hint. Take the build-in collection `set` for instance:

```
# way 1
def f(s: set[str]) -> str:
    pass

# way 2
def f(s: typing.Set[str]) -> str:
    pass

# way 3
def f(s: collections.abc.Set[str]) -> str:
    pass

# way 3': or arguable collections.abc.MutableSet vs collections.abc.Set
def f(s: collections.abc.MutableSet[str]) -> str:
    pass
```

Furthermore, for some abstract type there are two version in `typing` and `collections.abc`, take `Mapping` for instance:

```
def f(m: typing.Mapping[str, int]) -> int:
    pass

def f(m: collections.abc.Mapping[str, int]) -> int:
    pass
```

According to [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- **and preferably only one** --obvious way to do it.

I am confused which one is best?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using the `set[str]` style of typing. Looking at [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/):

> Importing those from typing is deprecated. Due to PEP 563 and the intention to minimize the runtime impact of typing, this deprecation will not generate DeprecationWarnings. Instead, type checkers may warn about such deprecated usage when the target version of the checked program is signaled to be Python 3.9 or newer.

So importing those from python's [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) package is now deprecated and you ideally should not be using those anymore; however, if you need to be backwards compatible with older versions of python, you can get by using them for now. Just be aware that in 5 years you may need to go in and update your code base since you will nedd python 3.9:

> Tooling, including type checkers and linters, will have to be adapted to recognize standard collections as generics.
>
> On the source level, the newly described functionality requires Python 3.9

Comment: Why not `collections.abc.Set`?

Comment: @KellyBundy If you look into the PEP 585 link I included you will find a list of the container types which are covered by the `set[...]` syntax. This list includes `collections.abc.Set # typing.AbstractSet`. Hope that helps

Comment: I saw that, but no, that doesn't help. What's your point with that? That list also includes `set # typing.Set`.

Comment: Yep, and that is the syntax that has been deprecated after python 3.9 ("Importing those from typing is deprecated"). You are still able to use it and probably should when you need to be backwards compatible. Python basically (not exactly) "bundled" all those types together so they can all be represented with a more generic `set[...]` syntax.

Comment: I still don't get it. You rule out `collections.abc.Set` because it's in that list but you don't rule out `set` even though it's also in that list?

Comment: it's in the list referencing `typing.Set`. Its entry is `set # typing.Set` the comment afterword clarifies their intention. Its definitely less clear than I would like, but the syntax I'm advocating for is used throughout as examples

Comment: I think that the examples (mostly) use the "shorter" ones is because they're shorter. Not because they're the only ones that should be used.

Comment: At the top they state "This PEP proposes to enable support for the generics syntax in all standard collections currently available in the typing module." which sounds like using the generic `set` to replace all of the other branches of collections types found in `collections` and `typing` to "make it easier for users to annotate their programs and easier for teachers to teach Python"

Comment: I don't see how that sounds like it's replacing those in `collections`. I mean, the quotes explicitly say "currently available in the **`typing`** module" and "Importing those from **`typing`** is deprecated".

Comment: Exactly, importing them is deprecated and the only thin left is to use the remaining `set`, `list`, etc. Before the collections list it states, “ This is why starting with Python 3.9, the following collections become generic using __class_getitem__() to parameterize contained types” so all the collection types in the following list are made generic using one approach which is the `set[...]` syntax. It is not replacing collections, just making them easier to use and more pythonic with one right way rather than 2-3. Only typing is deprecated from what I can tell.

Comment: It doesn't say importing those from `collections` is deprecated. And what does becoming generic have to do with this?

Comment: I haven said `collections` is deprecated, only `typing` is. By becoming generic I mean, there is one “generic” way to use all of them. You are still able to use `collections`, they are just providing a way to reference any of the standard collection types using the same syntax thus making “it easier for users to annotate their programs and easier for teachers to teach Python". To clarify, feel free to use `collections`, it’s not deprecated, but using `set[str]` is more concise, and provides the same overall functionality, making it the “preferred” method of annotating a collection value.

Comment: How about `collections.abc.Sequence` (as opposed to a more specific list or tuple)? Is `collections.abc` the canonical module to get a general `Sequence` for type hinting purposes starting from Python 3.9 and going forward? Same question for `MutableSequence`, `Mapping` and co. that don't have a corresponding built-in type.

Comment: hmmm, since there isn't a clear corresponding built in as you say, its best to use the `collections.abc` types since `collections` is still "allowed."